# Make Thunderbird3 not switch to firefox after clicking a link

Tags: firefox, thunderbird

Using ThunderBird 3 on Windows 7. When I get a mail with a link, I usually click it, if I know what it's about.

Sadly, Thunderbird switches to Firefox which is opening the new tab.
I'm active on several forums and get several of these messages per day. I don't want to click a link, be forced into firefox, go back to thunderbird, click a link, be forced into Firefox, etc...

Is there an option to disable this? If not, I can see myself quitting Thunderbird altogheter and simply using web-based email checking instead of using an app.

Comment: So you want the links to not work? Or do you want to fire another browser?

Comment: No, what I want is to click all the links, and firefox opens them just as normal. What I don't want is being switched to firefox everytime I click a link. I want to click them all, all why staying in Thunderbird, and then go to Firefox when I feel like it.

Comment: So open all the links you click on the background, but not change focus, not switch out the windows.

Comment: @Eight Days: this is what I want, but it seems that it is not possible to set this in the settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend going with the [ThunderBrowse](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/5373) extension.  Lets you view links in the message pane.

Edit:  Since you want the links to open in the background in a firefox window, try setting`browser.tabs.loadDivertedInBackground` to`true` in Firefox's `about:config`.  This should let you open any links sent from programs without bringing firefox to the front.

Comment: Sadly, I want them to open in Firefox, which this addon does not seem to offeR.

Comment: I agree with mattikus: this is a feature of Firefox, not Thunderbird. Setting browser.tabs.loadDivertedInBackground fixes this (but unfortunately it also does not focus the new tab)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by installing add-on "Tab Mix Plus" to Firefox.  Tab Mix Plus allows you to control if you want to change focus (when to switch to a window/app) when you click on links/bookmarks/etc.

After installation of add-on, open Tab Mix Plus options in Tools.
Click on Events tab.
Click on Tab Focus tab.
Uncheck all boxes under "Focus/Select tabs that open from:"
Click Close.

This should solve your problem.  Tab Mix Plus does not work with the latest Firebox 4 beta, however.

Cheers.

Comment: There's one answer above this one. That did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

THIS is the more permanent solution I think you're looking for - worked well for me, although you may have to repeat the exercise if you ever return Firefox to its default settings

> First, type (or copy and paste) "about:config" (minus quotes) into the Firefox address bar and hit enter.
>
> [image]
>
> In the Filter bar, type (or copy and paste) "browser.tabs.loadDivertedInBackground" minus the quotes.
>
> [image]
>
> By default, the value of this entry is false. To change it, double click the entry and it will toggle so that the value reads true. Restart Firefox and you're done.